# Hive date function to achieve day of week

Tags: apache, hive

I'm looking for a workaround or hive date functions that gives day of the week ,

```
Sunday - 1
Monday - 2
Tuesday - 3
Wednesday - 4
Thursday - 5
Friday - 6
Saturday - 7
```

Requirement in detail : I'm looking for a function that takes date string (YYYYMMDD) as input and outputs the day of the week as per the above table.

Comment: You need to write UDF for this.
Can you explain your requirement ? Also what is the data type of that column ?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

As I said you need to write a UDF which will accept a string as parameter and return a string.
Inside the UDF you need to do these steps:

1.) Parse the input string using **SimpleDateFormat(YYYYMMDD)**

2.) Use the Below code to get the day of week:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

3.) Use this **dayOfWeek** value in a **case statement** to get your weekday String and return that string.

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: Completely unnecessary to write your own UDF for this.

Answer (score 46):

Consider using `from_unixtime(your date,'u')` - this will return day number of week starting from `Monday=1`.
If your date is not in unixtime format, you can use the following instead:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20140112','yyyyMMdd'),'u')
```

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for simple date format documentation.

Comment: It works only from Java 7, on Java 6 it fails (no 'u' option in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Also, if you want the text version of the weekday (i.e. "Mon", "Tue" etc.), you can use `'E'` in place of `'u'`

Comment: Monday is 1, Sunday is 7

Comment: greatful if you could share any thoughts on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568002/how-to-set-simpledateformat-w-use-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-instead-of

Answer (score 24):

You can now use date_format (Hive 1.2):

```
hive> select date_format('2016-12-01' ,'u');
OK
4
```

Answer (score 13):

`select pmod(datediff(your_date,'1900-01-07'),7) + 1 as WeekDay from your_table`

- arbitrary start date picked (1900-01-07)
- calculates the mod 7 day of week (plus 1 to start at 1 instead of zero)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on iggy's answer, here is the query to get the days of the week. Adjust the query to set the first day of the week as necessary.

```
SELECT current_date AS `Date`,
       CASE date_format(current_date,'u')
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Mon'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Tues'
           WHEN 3 THEN 'Wed'
           WHEN 4 THEN 'Thu'
           WHEN 5 THEN 'Fri'
           WHEN 6 THEN 'Sat'
           WHEN 7 THEN 'Sun'
END AS day_of_week
```

Answer (score 0):

From Hive 2.2 there is another possibility:

```
hive> select extract(dayofweek FROM your_date) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select date_format(current_date, 'EEEE');
```

Which gives Sunday, Monday, Tuesday etc